# grep files with pattern A but exclude files with pattern B

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep, scripting

I want to grep files which include pattern A (iwant) but I want to exclude files which contain pattern B (idontwant).

Example:

```
read -p "...what are you looking for: " iwant
read -p "...what should not be included: " idontwant

iwant="blue car" 
idontwant="red car"
```

Just assume I have the following files:

```
-rw-rw-r--.  1 terpentin terpentin  45 Jun  8 16:04 blue.car
-rw-rw-r--.  1 terpentin terpentin  44 Jun  8 16:05 mixed.car
-rw-rw-r--.  1 terpentin terpentin  40 Jun  8 16:04 red.car
```

```
find . -type f -print -exec cat {} \;

./mixed.car
blue car
red car
blue car

./red.car
red car
red car
red car

./blue.car
blue car
blue car
blue car
```

How is it possible to get only the file "./blue.car" as a result?

The original content includes hundreds of long text files, which makes it important to be as resource-efficient as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
find . -type f ! -exec grep -q "$idontwant" {} ';' -exec grep -q "$iwant" {} ';' -print
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q "$iwant" {} ';' ! -exec grep -q "$idontwant" {} ';' -print
```

- The terms (sometimes called “predicates”) in a `find`
  command are characterized as *tests* (e.g., `-type f`)
  and *actions* (e.g., `-print` and `-delete`). 
  It might be hard to figure out from the man page
  that `-exec` is both an *action* and a *test*. 
  So, just as

  ```
  find . -type f -mtime -30 -name '*.txt' -readable -size +5 test6 test7 test8 …
  ```

  successively narrows the search to files that meet all the criteria
  (satisfy all the specified tests), so

  ```
  find . -exec cmd1 {} ';' -exec cmd2 {} ';' -exec cmd3 {} ';' …
  ```

  finds files for which all the commands succeed.
- Any `find` test can be negated (inverted) by preceding it with `!`. 
  So `find . ! -type d` finds plain files, symbolic links, named pipes, sockets, and device files — everything except directories.
- Note that `! -exec grep …` is not equivalent to `-exec grep -v …`. 
  `-exec grep -v …` will find files
  that have at least one line that doesn’t match. 
  `! -exec grep …` will find files where *no* lines match.
- The `-q` option to `grep` is officially a synonym for `--quiet`,
  but it also means **quick**. 
  It writes no output (except perhaps for error messages, as applicable),
  but also it exits as soon as it finds a match — 
  it doesn’t read every file to the end to find *every* match. 
  (Of course, if a file doesn’t contain any matches,
  then `grep` must read it in its entirety to determine that.)
- So (**TL;DR**) the commands find the files for which

  ```
  grep -q "$iwant"     file
  ```

  succeeds and

  ```
  grep -q "$idontwant" file
  ```

  fails
  (because we preceded it with `!`).
- The two commands are functionally equivalent,
  but may have different performance
  (i.e., may take different amounts of time to run). 
  If only a few files contain the search strings,

  ```
  find . -type f -exec grep -q "$iwant" {} ';' ! -exec grep -q "$idontwant" {} ';' –print
  ```

  will be faster,
  because the `grep "$iwant"` will eliminate most of the files. 
  If many of the files contain both strings, then

  ```
  find . -type f ! -exec grep -q "$idontwant" {} ';' -exec grep -q "$iwant" {} ';' –print
  ```

  will be faster,
  because the `! grep "$idontwant"` will eliminate most of the files.

Comment: OK, that was fast - Thanks for the help guys. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU grep` we can perform the filename extraction with a judicious choice of regex and grep options:

```
$ grep -lzPsr '(?s:(?=.*blue)(?!.*red))' .
```

We are operating grep in slurp mode (-z) wherein the whole file is treated as one big line.

The -l will list the filenames of file(s) matching the regex.

The -r will run recursively on all files in current dir nd below.

The -s will silence the grep to not emit any warnings.

The regex will look for the presence of blue and absence of red in a file for it to say yes.

The -P invokes the Perl regex engine in grep so that we can get the advantage of pcre regexes.